Ubuntu Won't Connect Ghost VPN After Update to 24.04
After the update from 22.04 to 24.04 I get this message when connecting to ghost VPN. I check and see my IP location has not changed.
System-Product-Name:~$ sudo cyberghostvpn --traffic --country-code US --connect
Prepare OpenVPN connection ...
Select server ... sanfrancisco-s404-i11
Connecting ... 
Downloading configuration ...

I reran System-Product-Name:~$ sudo cyberghostvpn --setup. Nothing changed after the command.

Does the command log messages somewhere? It may log to /var/log/syslog or it's own log. But without seeing log messages it's impossible to say why it does not work. Probably a question for the VPN providers support.

What command can I use to search for the logs? I asked ghost, and they admitted they didn't actually make their VPN compatible with the latest LTS version of Ubuntu.

I would start with running tail -f /var/log/syslog then see if any relevant messages/errors show when you run your command. Also sudo dmesg -w will do the same sort of thing as tail -f but for the kernal message buffer. It's possible your vpn logs to it's own logs which may be in /var/log or may be in /var/log/<some_sub_dir> or may be elsewhere...

You probably don't actually need the providers CLI program to use the service if they support OpenVPN. It's literally an open source VPN. You just need the configuration file/s from the provider and they seem to detail this manual setup here:
https://support.cyberghostvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012606699-How-to-use-CyberGhostVPN-on-Synology-NAS-via-OpenVPN
Follow the instructions up to downloading the .zip file, unzip the file, then in Ubuntu Network Settings click the + against VPN and choose Import from file...
Select the downloaded .ovpn file then you should just need to select the Identity/Authentication method which looks like from the link above to be Certificates rather than username/password. Select/import the certificates/key from the .zip and you should be good to go.

That worked. Intresting that tech support at Cyberghost didn't just tell me this. Can I unistall ghost from the CLI without affecting Synology? Also why is there a CLI and GUI version for VPN in ubuntu?

I can't find an option to have the VPN connect automatically. The guide page from your link above said there was supposed to be an option for this. Any suggestions?

It's kind of hidden away in an Advanced Network GUI. Run nm-connection-editor, select your Network Connection (NOT the VPN), click the Cog icon, click the General tab and check the Automatically connect to VPN box, then select the VPN connection you want and click Save.

I have the same problem,
I worked with Cyberghost VPN technical support. The reason why the CLI program does not connect is because the CLI application does not support Ubuntu 24.04.
The work around is to use the Network Manager application and to download the VPN certificates from Cyberghost.
Instructions on how to do this can be found here.
https://support.cyberghostvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007929314-Set-Up-OpenVPN-on-Linux-Ubuntu-via-Network-Manager
